# Multiple Join Showing More than One Record

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables - similar to the below. The first table stores information about each job:

```
+--------+------------+
| JOB_ID |  JOB_NAME  |
+--------+------------+
|        |            |
| 1      | Test Job 1 |
|        |            |
| 2      | Test Job 2 |
|        |            |
| 3      | Test Job 3 |
|        |            |
| 4      | Test Job 4 |
|        |            |
| 5      | Test Job 5 |
|        |            |
| 6      | Test Job 6 |
|        |            |
| 7      | Test Job 7 |
+--------+------------+
```

And the second table, stores one or more "subjects" relating to each job:

```
+------------+--------+------------------+
| SUBJECT_ID | JOB_ID |   SUBJECT_NAME   |
+------------+--------+------------------+
|            |        |                  |
| 1          | 1      | Test Subject #1  |
|            |        |                  |
| 2          | 1      | Test Subject #2  |
|            |        |                  |
| 3          | 1      | Test Subject #3  |
|            |        |                  |
| 4          | 2      | Test Subject #4  |
|            |        |                  |
| 5          | 3      | Test Subject #5  |
|            |        |                  |
| 6          | 3      | Test Subject #6  |
|            |        |                  |
| 7          | 3      | Test Subject #7  |
|            |        |                  |
| 8          | 4      | Test Subject #8  |
|            |        |                  |
| 9          | 5      | Test Subject #9  |
|            |        |                  |
| 10         | 6      | Test Subject #10 |
|            |        |                  |
| 11         | 7      | Test Subject #11 |
|            |        |                  |
| 12         | 7      | Test Subject #12 |
|            |        |                  |
| 13         | 7      | Test Subject #13 |
+------------+--------+------------------+
```

Currently, I have an SQL statement that shows all the jobs, and the first two "subjects" in two fields, result below:

```
+--------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| JOB_ID |  JOB_NAME  |    SUBJECT 1     |    SUBJECT 2     |
+--------+------------+------------------+------------------+
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 1      | Test Job 1 | Test Subject #1  | Test Subject #2  |
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 2      | Test Job 2 | Test Subject #4  |                  |
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 3      | Test Job 3 | Test Subject #5  | Test Subject #6  |
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 4      | Test Job 4 | Test Subject #8  |                  |
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 5      | Test Job 5 | Test Subject #9  |                  |
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 6      | Test Job 6 | Test Subject #10 |                  |
|        |            |                  |                  |
| 7      | Test Job 7 | Test Subject #11 | Test Subject #12 |
+--------+------------+------------------+------------------+
```

This is produced by the following SQL:

```
SELECT   job.job_id as 'Id',  
job.job_name as 'JobName', 
Subjects1.Subject as 'Subject 1', 
Subjects2.Subject as 'Subject 2', 
LEFT JOIN job_Subjects as Subjects1 ON Subjects1.job_id = job.job_id AND Subjects1.Subject_id = (SELECT Subject_id FROM job_Subjects WHERE job_Subjects.job_id = job.job_id ORDER BY job_Subjects.Subject_index LIMIT 1) 
LEFT JOIN job_Subjects as Subjects2 ON Subjects2.job_id = job.job_id AND Subjects2.Subject_id = (SELECT Subject_id FROM job_Subjects WHERE job_Subjects.job_id = job.job_id ORDER BY job_Subjects.Subject_index LIMIT 1,1)
```

However, I also need to search on the subject's name (the job_subjects.subject field).

I've tried the following:

- Added a "WHERE job_subjects.subject LIKE '%Test Job 3%'" - however I get the following error: "Unknown column 'job_subjects.subject ' in 'where clause'"
- Added another join "LEFT JOIN job_subjects as SearchSubjects ON SearchSubjects .job_id = job.job_id" and then "WHERE SearchSubjects.subject LIKE '%Test Job 3%'" however I seem to be getting multiple JOB results (in that, it seems to generate a job row result for every subject result it finds).

How can I search the subject table, while at the same time keeping the two joins the way they are?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a nice extension where you can use a `HAVING` clause to do what you want.  First, I would suggest that you use backtick for the columns names -- or use names that don't need to be escaped.

```
SELECT job.job_id as Id, job.job_name as JobName, 
       Subjects1.Subject as Subject1, 
       Subjects2.Subject as Subject2
FROM ?? LEFT JOIN
     job_Subjects Subjects1
     ON Subjects1.job_id = job.job_id AND
        Subjects1.Subject_id = (SELECT Subject_id FROM job_Subjects WHERE job_Subjects.job_id = job.job_id ORDER BY job_Subjects.Subject_index LIMIT 1
                               ) LEFT JOIN
     job_Subjects Subjects2
     ON Subjects2.job_id = job.job_id AND
        Subjects2.Subject_id = (SELECT Subject_id FROM job_Subjects WHERE job_Subjects.job_id = job.job_id ORDER BY job_Subjects.Subject_index LIMIT 1,1
                               ) 
HAVING Subject1 LIKE '%Test Job 3%';
```

You can also do this using a subquery.  That would be the more traditional approach.  However, MySQL materializes subqueries, incurring some overhead in performance.

Comment: Nice answer! one question... you say the subqueries would be extra overhead. Is that any different than the subquery on your join? Its almost like a dependent subquery except you are limiting it. Not sure I completely understand how that is more performant.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - it's actually giving me the results I want (which is awesome), however the query above is taking around 43 seconds to execute (previously around 1 - 2 seconds)...I guess I'll need to keep trying to improve/optimise the query?

Comment: @AndrewMilici . . . You might want to ask *another* query about how to make this faster.

Comment: @JohnRuddell . . . The subqueries on the `join` only return one row, so the materialization is not a big deal.  They are inefficient for a different reason.